# Different encodings every time I append to a CSV file

Tags: java, character-encoding, opencsv

I am appending text encoded in Windows-1252 into to a CSV in this way:

```java
public static final Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");


public void dumpToCSV(final List<String[]> content, 
                      final char delimiter, 
                      final String enc,
                      final int csvDays) {

    File file = new File(Constants.CSV_FILENAME);

    // Convert the Character Format before dumping to file:
    try (
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(file, true),  
            CHARSET);
        CSVWriter cw = new CSVWriter(os, delimiter)) {

        // Remove old lines
        clearCsvByDays(file, csvDays, Character.toString(delimiter));
        // Dump new content into file.  
        cw.writeAll(content);
  } catch (IOException e) {}
}

private void clearCsvByDays(final File file, final int csvDays, final String delim) 
             throws IOException {

    List<String> out = Files.lines(file.toPath(), CHARSET)
                            .filter(line -> mustFilter(line, csvDays, delim))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(file.toPath(), out, 
                StandardOpenOption.WRITE, 
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

The first writing to the file, the result is as expected, the characters are Windows-1252 encoded and are shown well on the target program .

```
"ʳpⲠ t촴";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0"     <-- This result is fine.
```

The second dump, it appends the new data on UTF-8, I don't know why.

```
"Éspáñà tëst";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0" <-- 2nd dump (new)
"ʳpⲠ t촴";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0"     <-- 1st dump (old)
```

The third dump, it appends the new data on another different encoding, but keeps the first correct line dumped on Windows-1252.

```
"ÃspÃ¡Ã±Ã  tÃ«st";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0"   <-- 3rd dump (new)
"Éspáñà tëst";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0"       <-- 2nd dump (old)
"ʳpⲠ t촴";"ADN";"26-09-2017";"0";"0";"0";"0"           <-- 1st dump (old)
```

If I keep appending, each time it is a different encoding.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where does `content` come from ?

Comment: First values are coming from a .properties file, so they must be manually populated. All 0 values are coming from a WS response.

Comment: You are using `CSVWriter` to write the data, but this is not a standard Java class.  Is there a bug in its implementation?  Hard to tell without knowing the code.

Comment: It is a [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSVWriter has been given a correct OutputStreamWriter.

And on writing, Files.write needs an encoding too.

```
Files.write(file.toPath(), out, CHARSET,
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

So I suspect hacks elsewhere:

```
new String(string.getBytes(...), ...)
```

Comment: I edited the question because I found the solution :P. Thank you for the help. I was going to post this same answer :).